# How can I make a DIV inside a DIV use 90% of the width?

Tags: html, css

I have tried this:

```
<div style="padding: 1rem 0;background-color:red">
   <div style="width: 90%;margin: 0 auto 0 auto; background-color:red">
   xxx
   </div>
</div>
```

But the inner DIV only occupies enough space for the xxx. How can I make that inner DIV have 90% of the width of the outer?

Comment: change the background colour of your inner div to some other colour and you'll see that the child div exactly occupies 90% width of its parent div.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is working fine you can't see that because both have red background color i changed it to green see this http://jsfiddle.net/vm3b350r/.

```html
<div style="padding: 1rem 0;background-color:red">
  <div style="width: 90%;margin: 0 auto 0 auto; background-color:green">
    xxx
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why repeat `0 auto` twice? Just `margin: 0 auto;` is fine.